# git says directory exists and is not empty, but Cd directory returns command not found

Tags: command-line, git

I have problem with installing wifiphisher on raspberry

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# git clone
https://github.com/wifiphisher/wifiphisher.git fatal: destination path
'wifiphisher' already exists and is not an empty directory.
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# Cd wifiphisher bash: Cd: command not found
```

I'm new to raspberry and wifiphisher. I have RaspberryPi 3

Comment: You have too many typos. Please learn bash, git, console and return back.

Comment: If you are using Raspbian, you should ask about it on [unix.se] or [raspberrypi.se], as we only support Ubuntu here. In any case, I suggest *not* running as root. It looks like you already closed the repo. Try the next instruction?

Comment: And, the command is `cd`, not `Cd`. Upper/lower case matters in Linux

Answer (score 7):

First of all, it says that wifiphisher is not an empty directory, and thus refuses to copy the data into it.

Next you run `Cd wifiphisher`, and you get the error `Cd: command not found`.

Unix (and Linux) is case sensitive. The command to change directory is `cd`, not `Cd`.

Thus, `cd wifiphisher` should work.

Comment: so you are saying I don't have problem in first one and      
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd wifiphisher
pi@raspberrypi:~/wifiphisher $

Comment: No, I'm saying that you should read, and try to understand, the error messages that turn up.